# With NLog can I set the property of a LayoutRender using the value of another one?

Tags: nlog

I'd like to use a LayoutRenderer in the configuration of another one, for example something like

```
${message:exceptionSeparator=${newline}:withException=true}
```

is that possible?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried: `${message:exceptionSeparator=\r\n:withException=true}` ?

Comment: yes, it's the workaround I'm using but I need another cfg file on linux to use \n so it's better if I can use ${newline}

Comment: Guess one could fix the NLog project so `exceptionSeparator` would recognize the keyword `${newline}` and do the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you can use this work-around:

```
${message}${onexception:${newline}}${exception:format=tostring}
```

But yes it would be nice to support string-literal-tokens like `${newline}` for standard string-properties.

Comment: currently I'm using a variable containing the different rendering logic because I need to reuse it in different layouts. 
anyhow my question is about the generic problem of referencing a LayoutRenderer within the configuration of another one (maybe in future I'll need it in another scenario than this) but after a week of research I don't think is possible :(
thanks for your help @rolf

Comment: @kk. It is possible as you can see from `${onexception:${newline}}`, but it requires that the property assigned is of type NLog `Layout` (And not string like `exceptionSeparator`)